# NAT: accept a connection and then forward it?

Tags: iptables, nat, load-balancing

In linux (or BSD), is it possible to accept an incoming connection, read the first payload packet, and then forward the connection to another server based on the contents of that packet? I'm not blind to the difficulties, and this probably needs to stay in the kernel for performance reasons outside of the initial connection.

Comment: Everything is possible in principle, but (1) this is not what you'd call NAT, (2) it's closer to load balancing (there are kernel solutions for that, but without packet inspection as far as I know, but possibly you can integrate eBPF with those), and (3) depending on the protocol(s) the connections will use, there might be better solutions.

Comment: historical linux link to outdated things from more than 10 years ago http://kb.linuxvirtualserver.org/wiki/Layer-7_switching to get the concept on what has to be done (to be clear: none of it appears to exist anymore). With this vocabulary you can find other informations. eg with tcp splice : https://blog.cloudflare.com/sockmap-tcp-splicing-of-the-future/ which is based on eBPF as dirkt said.